# confidence and estimating

Tags: statistics

You wish to estimate,with 99% confidence, the proportion of Canadian drivers who want the speed limit raised to 130 kph. Your estimate must be accurate to within 5%. How many drivers must you survey,if your initial estimate of the proportion is 0.60?

I know that 99% is 2.575 but I don't know how to set up the problem. I don't think that 130 kph even has anything to do with the problem. I think i am over thinking this question.

I think it would be about 93 people. Is that right?

Comment: Here is a related article http://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/pd006

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be the appropriate sample size. Then the variance of the sample mean is $$\frac{p(1-p)}{n},$$ where $p$ is the true population proportion. We will use our preliminary estimate  $p\approx 0.6$ to estimate the variance of the sample mean. The reason we can do that is that the standard deviation of the sample mean is fairly insensitive to the actual value of $p$.

Using the normal approximation, we find that the probability that the sample mean differs by more than $0.05$ from the true $p$ is approximately
$$\Pr\left(|Z|\gt \frac{0.05}{\sqrt{(0.6)(0.4)/n}}\right),$$
where $Z$ is standard normal. So we want
$$\frac{0.05}{\sqrt{(0.6)(0.4)/n}}\approx 2.575.$$
Now we can find $n$. It is quite a bit bigger than $93$.